# How to fix Crawled (403)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am using python 3 and scrapy. I am fetching in scrapy shell with this code:

```
url = "https://www.urban.com.au/projects/melbourne-square-93-119-kavanagh-street-southbank"
headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"

}

fet = scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)
fetch(fet)
```

and it's showing `DEBUG: Crawled (403)`

Please share any idea with return 200 response in scrapy shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you open it in your browser it's showing fill captcha to proceed. So for high traffic from a computer, it will ask for extra authentication.

Hence you're seeing 403

Answer (score 0):

403 error - because website showing a captcha.
If resolve the captcha and extract cookie it will be work.
Example with `requests` for debug:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'your cookie',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.urban.com.au/projects/melbourne-square-93-119-kavanagh-street-southbank', headers=headers)
```

Comment: How do you obtain the cookie, I am curious about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.urban.com.au',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'dnt': '1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',

}

Request('https://www.urban.com.au/projects/melbourne-square-93-119-kavanagh-street-southbank', headers=headers)
```

You need to mimic exact same header as a real browser does

Comment: No luck! still 403